# python 2.7 | carriage return not working

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, carriage-return

I am trying to use `\r` to print to the same line in bash (Ubuntu 16.04 terminal) but it doesn't work, as the program still prints frame number in a new line.

Here is the code

```
i = 0
while img is not None:
    print "Frame Number: {0}  \r".format(i)
    result = unwarp(img, xmap, ymap)
    result.save(disp)
    # Save to file
    fname = "../temp_data/frames/FY{num:06d}.png".format(num=i)
    result.save(fname)        
    img = vc.getImage()
    i = i + 1
```

I even tried using `\x08` like this

```
print "Frame Number: {0}  \xO8".format(i)
```

but its still not working.

here is a sample output:

```
Frame Number: 0  
Frame Number: 1  
Frame Number: 2  
Frame Number: 3  
Frame Number: 4  
Frame Number: 5  
Frame Number: 6  
Frame Number: 7  
Frame Number: 8
```

Comment: @TankorSmash oops I meant to say " output by the way" and I made a typo. I'll correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
print "\rFrame Number: {:06d}".format(i),
```

Note the trailing `,` character on the print statement.

Comment: wow this worked. can you please explain how it works?

Comment: That's just the Python 2 syntax for not appending a new-line automatically on a print statement.  Weird, I know... it was fixed in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks so much. and I notice that the line doesn't refresh spontaneously. is this bash related?

Comment: That's about output buffering - often stdout is line buffered.  If you add a call to `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print statement, you should see every line